# Can return response from REDIS subscribe?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, subscribe, predis

I use predis and i want subscribe to channel in PHP and wait 30 seconds. If not receive any messages at channel, return json response. Or if messages in channel exists, return response too and exit.

For example i want, that my Redis::subscribe return $message and i can return response.

I have a some code in Controller in Laravel:

```
 Redis::subscribe(['PushAuthChanel'], function($message) {


  echo $message; // Nothing happens
  return response()->json($c, 200); // Nothing happens
  //return $message; // Nothing happens too

    });
```

And why Redis::subscribe can not return $message?
But it well return exit code like this:

```
Redis::subscribe(['PushAuthChanel'], function($message) {


return exit(0); //will work
dd($message); //will work fine

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you still waiting for answer? Any way. You can change your code like this:

```
    $pubsub = Redis::pubSubLoop();
    $pubsub->subscribe('channel-name');
    foreach ($pubsub as $message) {
        print_r ($message);
        // You can unsubscribe any time you want by using this function:
        // $pubsub->unsubscribe();
    }
```

Comment: That looks like it solves half the question - subscribing and inspecting the messages. Any hints on how a 30 second period could be set? Would that need to be an external timer?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue, and resolved it by:

Connection to redis, I set `'read_timeout' => 30`, it throws `RedisException` on read (subscribe) timeout, so we can catch that

```
try {
    Redis::subscribe(['channel-name'], function ($message) {
        die($message);
    });
} catch (\RedisException $exception) {
    return \Response::json([
        'timeout' => true
    ], 204);
}
```

On timeout, code response `204` (no content), so in this case client make immediately connect again (something as long polling connection)